# Specifying the c2dm client login token while uploading the android app into market

Tags: android, google-play, android-c2dm

I need to specify the C2DM Client Login Token in developer Console while uploading my app into market as my app is using c2dm service. 
Here are my doubts : 1 Is this token for one time or every time? 2. What should i do if it updates token after uploading my app into market? Is earlier token still valid? can i get notifications still? Please help me out.

Comment: C2DM(was beta) is deprecated, you should use GCM(released and simplyfied version) instead

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please switch to GCM as soon as possible.

1 Is this token for one time or every time?
  A: Yes, once Google provides a token for a device, it remains the same. (If, in near future, you decide to switch to GCM, then a new key will be generated for that device.)

1. What should i do if it updates token after uploading my app into market?
   A: In this case, make you app collect the registration key on start up every time.
   Check your shared pref if the key has changed or not. If yes, update the database on your server side accordingly.

Comment: client login token is about server side or device side?